# Why doesn't my calculation summarise according to date but instead keep giving me the same overall value each time?

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping, summarization

I have a data frame that I have grouped on one column (date / `_source.time`) and then summarised.

I keep running into an issue when trying to perform a calculation (orders/date_count) that always produces an overall value as opposed to the grouped (date) equivalent.

The problem exists because the fields `leads_T_orders` and `leads_F_orders` produce the same value all the way along the column.  Once these values match their respective grouped dates, the `leads_T_conv` and `leads_F_conv` calculations should be correct.

I want to do `orders / date_count` for each date (`_source.time`) grouping but I keep getting the same value all the way along the column.

`date_count` is the sum of `leads_TRUE`, `leads_FALSE` and `no_claim_event`, so each version of `orders` (`leads_T_orders`, `leads_F_orders`) will be divided by their respective `date_count` counterpart.

Where am I going wrong?

This is the code:

```
gn %>%
  group_by(`_source.time`) %>%
  summarize(
    leads_TRUE = sum(lead == TRUE),
    leads_FALSE = sum(lead == FALSE),
    no_claim_event = sum(lead == "no-claim-event"),
    leads_T_orders = sum(gn$orders[gn$lead == TRUE]),
    leads_F_orders = sum(gn$orders[gn$lead == FALSE]),
    date_count = sum(leads_TRUE + leads_FALSE + no_claim_event), # Equal to total number of chats occurring each day.
    leads_T_conv = sum(leads_T_orders / leads_TRUE),
    leads_F_conv = sum(leads_F_orders / leads_FALSE),
    missing_claim_conv = sum(orders / nrow(gn[gn$lead == "no-claim-event", ])),
    overall_conv = sum(leads_T_conv + leads_F_conv + missing_claim_conv)
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
```

And it produces this:

```
# A tibble: 64 x 11
   `_source.time` leads_TRUE leads_FALSE no_claim_event leads_T_orders leads_F_orders date_count leads_T_conv leads_F_conv
   <date>              <int>       <int>          <int>          <int>          <int>      <int>        <dbl>        <dbl>
 1 2018-05-14              8          86              9             73            216        103      0.00363     0.00181 
 2 2018-05-15             29          71              0             73            216        100      0.00242     0.00121 
 3 2018-05-16             27          82              0             73            216        109      0.00545     0.00272 
 4 2018-05-17             19           1              1             73            216         21      0.00121     0.000604
```

**Note that the data frame in question contains private data, so I can't provide a `dput()` of it but this question is more around how the `group_by()` function works as opposed to the data themselves.**

Comment: Don't use `gn$` with `dplyr` if you want groupwise operation. By calling the values with `gn$`, the full vector will be used, ignoring any `group_by` operations used before.

Comment: I understand that, it makes perfect sense, but my question then is how do I count the `order` values for those instances where `lead == TRUE` within the grouping?

Comment: You can use `ifelse` statements along with the `na.rm = TRUE` argument to do this. For example: `sum(ifelse(lead, orders, NA), na.rm = TRUE)`